# Fill javascript array using jstl array

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp, jstl

I have a jstl array with,

```
<sql:query var="list_str" dataSource="${myDS}">
    SELECT * FROM str;
</sql:query>
```

Now i want to fill a single column content of the table str in a javascript array. I am trying this.

```
<c:forEach items="${list_str.rows}" var="user" varStatus="status">
    var val = ${user.Name};
    fruits.push(val);
</c:forEach>
```

But, the fruits array value is empty, can anyone please guide how to accomplish this.

Comment: Did you have a look a the generated client-side source code?

Comment: `var val= <c:out value="${user.Name}"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `var val` and you need quotes around what will become a hard-coded string literal in the resulting javascript code.

```
<c:forEach items="${list_str.rows}" var="user" varStatus="status">
    fruits.push('${user.Name}');
</c:forEach>
```